# How to use CakePHP3 "Authentication" Plugin with JWT

Tags: php, authentication, cakephp, jwt, cakephp-3.x

I have installed CakePhp 3.8 and i need use JWT authentication.

I have tryed installing and configuring CakePHP/Authentication (https://book.cakephp.org/authentication/1.1/en/index.html) but can not configure this.

My configuration:

- PHP 7.2.19
- MySQL 5.7.27
- Apache 2.4.29
- CakePHP 3.8
- Authentication Plugin 1.1
- firebase/php-jwt

I followed the guide configurations, and have add at AppController.php

```
// /src/Controller/Appcontroller.php
 public function initialize()
    {
        parent::initialize();
        $this->loadComponent('Authentication.Authentication', [
            'logoutRedirect' => '/administrators/login'  // Default is false
        ]);
....
```

In Application.php

```
// /src/application.php
class Application extends BaseApplication implements AuthenticationServiceProviderInterface

....

public function getAuthenticationService(ServerRequestInterface $request, ResponseInterface $response)
    {
        $service = new AuthenticationService();
        $service->loadIdentifier('Authentication.JwtSubject');
        $service->loadAuthenticator('Authentication.Jwt', [
            'returnPayload' => false
        ]);
        return $service;
    }

....

public function middleware($middlewareQueue)
    {
....

        // Add the authentication middleware
        $authentication = new AuthenticationMiddleware($this);

        // Add the middleware to the middleware queue
        $middlewareQueue->add($authentication);

        return $middlewareQueue;
    }
```

How i can login for first time and retrive JWT token?

-------------------EDIT-------------------

Thankyou, your solutions workly perfectly.

But now i have CORS problem with Angular FE GET request, befor GET this try one OPTIONS request whit CORS error.

I have this CORS policy in my AppController

```
        // Accepted all CORS
        $this->response = $this->response->cors($this->request)
            ->allowOrigin(['*'])
            ->allowMethods(['GET','POST','PUT','DELETE','OPTIONS','PATCH']) // edit this with more method
            ->allowHeaders(['X-CSRF-Token']) //csrf protection for cors
            ->allowCredentials()
            ->exposeHeaders(['Link'])
            ->maxAge(60)
            ->build();
```

Comment: Add the form authenticator and have an action that allows login via username/email and password. When the login is successful you generate the token and use it from there on in every future request. The form authenticator is not persisting or reading the data from the session! It will just retrieve it for the current request when it includes the form data. There is also a framework agnostic version of the former plugin I've created https://github.com/Phauthentic/authentication I'll add a complete example for JWT tomorrow. :)

Comment: Added it to the docs, it should be pretty much the same in Cake https://github.com/Phauthentic/authentication/blob/master/docs/JWT-Example.md I would recommend the lib over the Cake plugin because it doesn't depend on a CakePHP version it won't get you into trouble when you need to update the framework. Also the implementation got a cleanup and is using types for everything.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You'd have to handle that on your own, ie create an endpoint that handles login requests, and upon successful authentication creates a JWT token containing the required identifier.

For `username`/`password` authentication for example you can use the `Form` authenticator and the `Password` identifier:

```php
$service->loadIdentifier('Authentication.Password');
$service->loadIdentifier('Authentication.JwtSubject');

$service->loadAuthenticator('Authentication.Form', [
    'loginUrl' => '/users/login'
]);
$service->loadAuthenticator('Authentication.Jwt', [
    'returnPayload' => false
]);
```

With that example in `UsersController` create a `login()` action like this (that's just a very basic, hopefully self-explanatory example), check the authentication status, if valid generate a token, if invalid generate an error:

```php
public function login()
{
    if ($this->Authentication->getResult()->isValid()) {
        $userId = $this->Authentication->getIdentityData('id');
        $token = \Firebase\JWT\JWT::encode(
            ['sub' => $userId],
            \Cake\Utility\Security::getSalt()
        );

        $status = 200;
        $response = [
            'token' => $token,
        ];
    } else {
        $status = 403;
        $response = [
            'error' => 'Authentication required',
        ];
    }

    return $this
        ->getResponse()
        ->withStatus($status)
        ->withType('json')
        ->withStringBody(json_encode($response));
}
```

It probably wouldn't hurt if the cookbook would have a complete example for token authentication.

See also

- **[Authentication Cookbook > Migration from the AuthComponent > Login action](https://book.cakephp.org/authentication/1.1/en/migration-from-the-authcomponent.html#login-action)**
- **[Authentication Cookbook > Quick Start > Checking the login status](https://book.cakephp.org/authentication/1.1/en/index.html#checking-the-login-status)**
- **[Authentication Cookbook > Quick Start > Using Stateless Authenticators with other Authenticators](https://book.cakephp.org/authentication/1.1/en/index.html#using-stateless-authenticators-with-other-authenticators)**

Comment: I love you, this work !

Thanks!

But now i have CORS problem, expose this in main post.

Comment: @DanieleCancani That's a completely different problem, I'd suggest that you open a new question where you can properly elaborate on the problem, supply code, etc.